# Subtracting elements of two sublists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists:

```
listA = {{h1, h2, h3}, {h4, h5, h6}, {h7, h8, h9}};
listB = {{g1, g2, g3}, {g4, g5, g6}};
```

and I need to subtract sublists to construct a list

```
listC = {{{h1 - g1, h2 - g2, h3 - g3}, 
          {h4 - g1, h5 - g2, h6 - g3},
          {h7 - g1, h8 - g2, h9 - g3}},
         {{h1 - g4, h2 - g5, h3 - g6},
          {h4 - g4, h5 - g5, h6 - g6},
          {h7 - g4, h8 - g5, h9 - g6}}}
```

Can someone enlighten me on how to do it?
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `-Outer[Subtract, listB, listA, 1]`?

Comment: As simple as I thought it should be. Great. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can most elegantly use the `Outer` function

```
- Outer[Subtract, listB, listA, 1]
```

A more tedious way would be to use list indices like `listB[[i]]....` in a `For` loop (I did not do that).